# A basis of a subspace is subset of a basis of the whole space

Tags: linear-algebra

If $X$ is a vector space with a basis $B$ and $A$ is a subspace of $X$. Does $A $always has a basis subset of $B$?
If yes, how should I prove this?

If no, we should give an example of a vector space $X$ with a basis $B$ and a subspace $A$ of $X$ such that any basis of $A$ is not subset of $B$.

Answer (score 11):

No. Look at the plane $\mathbb R^2$ with the usual basis vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ and the subspace $A = \{(x,x) : x \in \mathbb R\}$.

Comment: Thanks so what if both the space and the subspace have the same dimension?

Comment: $\{(1,1), (-1,1)\}$ is a basis of the plane.

Comment: I mean, What if we repeat the same question with extra condition that both X and A are n-dimensional ?

Comment: @Sara if space and subspace have the same dimension then, space and subspace are equal